# Add comma after each added words in jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to add comma after adding each word in a textarea. 
eg,. word1, word2, word3

In this textarea the user can add words by getting words in a select box and click the add button or by manual input by user. The current working is the adding of words by using the select box. When I add words from select box, I can achieved the output word1, word2, word3 
The problem is that when the user manually type the words and then add words using selectbox at the same time. It produces output like this. eg., word1 word2, word3 
 
As you can see there is no comma after the word1. Any idea?

```
$('#addWordsearch').click(function() {

    if($('#wsearch_lesson_zone_list').val() == null)
    {
      alert("Add words first");
      return false;
    } 

    else
    {

        $('#search_word').val($('#search_word').val() + $('#wsearch_lesson_zone_list').val() + ", ");

    }  
});
```

Comment: [`.split(/\s+/g)`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split)[`.join(', ')`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/join)

Comment: How can I apply that sir? thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you are not adding the comma for the manually typed word. You are just taking the manually typed word and adding with select box. You can try like the following:

```
$('#addWordsearch').click(function() {

if($('#wsearch_lesson_zone_list').val() == null)
{
  alert("Add words first");
  return false;
} 

else
{

var text = $('#search_word').val(),
    selectText = $('#wsearch_lesson_zone_list').val();
text = text ? text + ", " + selectText :selectText ;  // adding comma if we have word in the textarea. 
$('#search_word').val( text);

}  
});
```

Comment: This output the word, but only the first word, the succeeding inputs only displays comma